# How to Display posting lists or Doc IDs for each term of query in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I need to extract the entire posting list for each term of the query in Lucene 3.5.0. I have created the indexes. My problem is that I do not know how to get the doc ids for a particular index terms. I read all the methods of IndexReader class, which has methods to give the count of docs referring to any index term, but could not figure how to get the the set of docIds referring to any index term. Please help.Please suggest some example code for me. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

That's what searching does.  Just search using a `TermQuery` to get all the docIds for a given term:

```
TopDocs docs = searcher.search(new TermQuery(new Term("myField", "term")), maxHits);
for (ScoreDoc doc : docs.scoreDocs) {
    int docid = doc.doc;
    //Do something with it...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But this will search the query term & get the doc list.....Can we DocEnums to retrieve the entire posting list for each of the query term directly? Say for example  for query "silver truck", 40 docs contain silver & 25 docs contain truck keyword. I wish to extract the docids of these 65 docs.

Comment: Again, that is exactly what searching lucene does. Gets (and scores) the docids for the query terms. That is how the inverted index works. In what way is that *not* doing what you are asking? Using `DocsEnum`s and such to do it might be possible, but would only serve to make it more confusing, and probably quite a bit slower.